# ArrayList and object issue

Tags: java

I tried to create ArrayList with Ingredients object and then iterate through this list but this is only showing the last added ingredient. For example when I'm adding two ingredients (mushrooms, tomatoes) in arrayList are only tomatoes with index 0 and 1.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Ingredients {

    private String ingredientName;
    private int ingriedientQuantity;

    List<Ingredients> ingredients;

    public Ingredients() {

        this.ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public void addIngredient(Ingredients ingredient) {

        ingredients.add(ingredient);
    }

    public String getIngredientName() {
        return ingredientName;

    }

    public void setIngredientName(String ingredientName) {
        this.ingredientName = ingredientName;

    }

    public int getIngriedientQuantity() {
        return ingriedientQuantity;
    }

    public void setIngriedientQuantity(int ingriedientQuantity) {
        this.ingriedientQuantity = ingriedientQuantity;
    }

    public void showIngredients() {
        for (Ingredients ingredientI : ingredients) {
            System.out.println(ingredientI.getIngredientName() + " " + ingredientI.getIngriedientQuantity());
        }

    }

}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Ingredients ing = null;
        boolean exitFlag = false;

        String name;
        int quantity;

        int option = 0;
        String o;

        while (!exitFlag) {
            System.out.println("1 - Add");
            System.out.println("2 - Show");
            System.out.println("3 - Exit");
            option = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();

            switch (option) {
            case 1:

                ing = new Ingredients();

                do {

                    System.out.println("Product name: ");
                    name = sc.nextLine();

                    ing.setIngredientName(name);
                    System.out.println("Quantity");
                    quantity = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    ing.setIngriedientQuantity(quantity);

                    System.out.println("Add more? Y/N");
                    o = sc.nextLine();

                    ing.addIngredient(ing);
                } while (!o.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));

                break;
            case 2:
                ing.showIngredients();
                break;

            case 3:
                exitFlag = true;

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error");
                break;
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Is better way to do it?

Comment: Every time you choose `1`, you replace the object, so you also replace the list.

Comment: Your implementation is really weird. How come an ingredient has itself a list of ingredients?

Comment: I know but I choose 1 once and then I'm adding ingredients until I choose "N"

Comment: Should I create another class and in this class add List and method with adding ingredients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class design is wrong. Create a separate class `Ingredient` with properties `IngredientName` and `IngredientQuantity`. The `Ingredients` class maintains an ArrayList for `Ingredient` objects.
A sample `Ingredient` class may look like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Ingredient {

private String ingredientName;
private int ingriedientQuantity;

public Ingredient() {

}

public String getIngredientName() {
    return ingredientName;

}

public void setIngredientName(String ingredientName) {
    this.ingredientName = ingredientName;

}

public int getIngriedientQuantity() {
    return ingriedientQuantity;
}

public void setIngriedientQuantity(int ingriedientQuantity) {
    this.ingriedientQuantity = ingriedientQuantity;
}

}
```

Your `Ingredients` can be implemented as:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Ingredients {

List<Ingredient> ingredients;

public Ingredients() {

    this.ingredients = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();

}

public void addIngredient(Ingredient ingredient) {

    ingredients.add(ingredient);
}

public void showIngredients() {
    for (Ingredient ingredientI : ingredients) {
        System.out.println(ingredientI.getIngredientName() + " " + ingredientI.getIngriedientQuantity());
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personnaly create a "Recipe" Class as follow :

```
public class Recipe {

    private List<Ingredients> ingredients;

    + getters and setters
}
```

Then change a little bit your ingredient class :

```
public class Ingredient {

     private String ingredientName;
     private int ingredientQuantity;

...

}
```

Then in your main method create a Recipe at the beginning, and then in your while loop create a **new instance** of Ingredient each time and add it to your recipe.

Comment: In the future I want to create recipe with name field and Ingredients List and add this Recipe to another List